# I want to over ride Style-l.less file in Magento blank theme?

Tags: css, less-css, custom-theme

I have created Custom theme which is inheriting Magento Blank theme... Now I want over ride CSS in style-l.less file of Blank theme How can I do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the same folder structure which defines in Magento Blank Theme.
For example, you want to override `style-l.less` then follow this one.

```
app/design/CustomTheme/name/web/css/style-l.less
```

That's it. now you can add your customization.